# How to specify a default value for a field Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-nova

I want to set the default value of a resource field to the authenticated user's `id`. I have a model called `Note` which has a one to many relationship with `Game` and `User`.

```
User hasMany Note
Game hasMany Note

Note belongsTo User
Note belongsTo Game
```

In Laravel Nova my fields looks like this for the note

```
ID::make()->sortable(),
Text::make('Note', 'note')->onlyOnIndex(),
Textarea::make('Note', 'note')->alwaysShow(),
BelongsTo::make('Game', 'game')->hideWhenCreating()->hideWhenUpdating(),
BelongsTo::make('Created By', 'user', 'App\Nova\User')->hideWhenCreating()->hideWhenUpdating(),
DateTime::make('Created At', 'created_at')->hideWhenCreating(),
DateTime::make('Updated At', 'updated_at')->hideWhenCreating(),
```

Because I am referencing the `Note` on the `Game` Nova resource, when I create a `Note`, the `game_id` column is populated correctly. But, I want the `user_id` column to be the value of the authenticated user. It does not seem to work like this, how would I accomplish it?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly from the line `BelongsTo::make('Created By', 'user', 'App\Nova\User')->hideWhenCreating()->hideWhenUpdating()` you're trying to set a default value for the column without showing the field on the form?

I don't think this is possible in this way. As soon as you use the `hide` functions the fields aren't rendered and will never be passed along with the request. I tried this, and the `user_id` field was never sent with the request.

I think there are two ways to do this:

Show the field in the form and set the default value using the metadata (and perhaps making the field read-only for good measure).

```
BelongsTo::make('Created By', 'user', 'App\Nova\User')->withMeta([
    "belongsToId" => auth()->user()->id,
])
```

[See this part of the Nova docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/fields.html#text-field)

Or use the Eloquent `creating` event. The following will go in your Note model.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($note)
    {
        $note->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    });
}
```

Granted, the above method is a bit simple. You'd be better off using proper event listeners.

Sidenote: from an architectural point of view, I'd go with option 2. Setting a default value without getting the end-user involved sounds like a job for the Eloquent model, not for a Nova form.

Comment: Hi @hoolakoola if this has solved your question please consider accepting it Or would you like some more help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a method `resolveUsing()`. An example

```
<?php

//...

Select::make('My Select', 'my_custom_name')
   ->options(['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c'])
   ->resolveUsing(function ($value, $resource, $attribute) {
      // $value = model attribute value
      // $attribute = 'my_custom_name'
      return 'b';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the BelongsTo field value to null, depending on other field value in the resource. This is how I've done it with NovaDependencyContainer:

```php
Select::make(__('admin.user.type'), 'user_type')
    ->options([
        'employee' => 'Employee',
        'other_employee' => 'Bank Employee',
    ]),

NovaDependencyContainer::make([
    BelongsTo::make(__('admin.user.employee_id'), 'employee', Employee::class)
        ->required()
        ->searchable(),
])->dependsOn('user_type', 'employee'),
NovaDependencyContainer::make([
    Text::make(__('admin.user.employee_id'), 'employee_id')
        ->readonly()
        ->nullable()
        ->resolveUsing(fn() => null),
])->dependsOn('user_type', 'other_employee'),
```